# Find Nuget runtime value for $version$ /assemblyVersion

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, csproj, nuspec

After doing some research microsoft's documention says AssembyVersion should be in the AssemblyInfo.cs or in the .csproj file.

However i found some examples like https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana having the version listed under CommonAssemblyInfo.cs for all subproject,
And in other cases the AssemblyVersion is wrapped in IF ELSE statements according to the runtime environment.
Here is the metadata of the .nuspec file

```
 <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>$authors$</authors>
    <owners>$authors$</owners>
    <copyright>© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <licenseUrl>$licenseUrl$</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>$projectUrl$</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <description>Provides middleware components to assist in developing OWIN-based applications.</description>
    <tags>$tags$</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Owin" version="1.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin" version="$version$" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the actual AssemblyVersion that is used at compile/runtime?

Maybe using dotnet.exe/nuget.exe?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the scenario?  Can you explain what you need it for?

Comment: I'm working on a tool that parse dependencies for open source projects, usually I parse the .csproj/.nuspec files but in cases like https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.nuspec I can't retrieve that is the value of the $version$ token in the dependencies

Comment: So you are parsing code files or actual assemblies?

Comment: I'm not parsing the code, I parse .csproj/.nuspec files to determine the packages were used.

Comment: That is what I mean..... Why are you not getting the version from the assemblies themselves?  Why do you need to read the csproj files? Are you compiling the nuget packages yourself rather than just referencing them?  I still do not understand what you are trying to do